# Activerecord model saved again after save... why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem.
I have a cover modem with some associated items.

I add an after save callback and I print the model in console using pry.

```
[#<Cover::Item:0x007fe190819920
12:22:32 web.1       |   id: 284,
12:22:32 web.1       |   cover_id: 64,
12:22:32 web.1       |   teaser_id: 214,
12:22:32 web.1       |   position: 2,
12:22:32 web.1       |   created_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 16:54:47 CEST +02:00,
12:22:32 web.1       |   updated_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00>,
12:22:32 web.1       |  #<Cover::Item:0x007fe190819740
12:22:32 web.1       |   id: 285,
12:22:32 web.1       |   cover_id: 64,
12:22:32 web.1       |   teaser_id: 210,
12:22:32 web.1       |   position: 3,
12:22:32 web.1       |   created_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 16:54:47 CEST +02:00,
12:22:32 web.1       |   updated_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00>,
12:22:32 web.1       |  #<Cover::Item:0x007fe190819560
12:22:32 web.1       |   id: 290,
12:22:32 web.1       |   cover_id: 64,
12:22:32 web.1       |   teaser_id: 54,
12:22:32 web.1       |   position: 4,
12:22:32 web.1       |   created_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 17:44:27 CEST +02:00,
12:22:32 web.1       |   updated_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00>,
12:22:32 web.1       |  #<Cover::Item:0x007fe190818548
12:22:32 web.1       |   id: 300,
12:22:32 web.1       |   cover_id: 64,
12:22:32 web.1       |   teaser_id: 207,
12:22:32 web.1       |   position: 1,
12:22:32 web.1       |   created_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00,
12:22:32 web.1       |   updated_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00>]
```

When I press ctrl+d to continue activerecord update the timestamp

```
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.7ms)  UPDATE "covers" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:21:40.388037' WHERE "covers"."id" = $1  [["id", 64]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "teasers" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:21:40.391480' WHERE "teasers"."type" IN ('Content::Teaser') AND "teasers"."id" = $1  [["id", 219]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.1ms)  UPDATE "contents" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:22:58.387353' WHERE "contents"."type" IN ('Content::News') AND "contents"."id" = $1  [["id", 223]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.2ms)  UPDATE "teasers" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:21:40.413622' WHERE "teasers"."type" IN ('Content::Teaser') AND "teasers"."id" = $1  [["id", 214]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.2ms)  UPDATE "contents" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:22:58.392526' WHERE "contents"."type" IN ('Content::News') AND "contents"."id" = $1  [["id", 218]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.2ms)  UPDATE "teasers" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:21:40.425685' WHERE "teasers"."type" IN ('Content::Teaser') AND "teasers"."id" = $1  [["id", 210]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "contents" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:22:58.397827' WHERE "contents"."type" IN ('Content::News') AND "contents"."id" = $1  [["id", 214]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.2ms)  UPDATE "teasers" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:21:40.437788' WHERE "teasers"."type" IN ('Content::Teaser') AND "teasers"."id" = $1  [["id", 54]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.2ms)  UPDATE "contents" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:22:58.404283' WHERE "contents"."type" IN ('Content::News') AND "contents"."id" = $1  [["id", 56]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.1ms)  UPDATE "teasers" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:21:40.444118' WHERE "teasers"."type" IN ('Content::Teaser') AND "teasers"."id" = $1  [["id", 207]]
12:22:58 web.1       |   SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "contents" SET "updated_at" = '2018-08-08 16:22:58.409152' WHERE "contents"."type" IN ('Content::News') AND "contents"."id" = $1  [["id", 211]]
12:22:58 web.1       |    (2.5ms)  COMMIT
```

Here is the problem. I add another pry in the view and If I print my model here is the log.

```
 [#<Cover::Item:0x007fe1a6f4f828
13:03:37 web.1       |   id: 300,
13:03:37 web.1       |   cover_id: 64,
13:03:37 web.1       |   teaser_id: 207,
13:03:37 web.1       |   position: 1,
13:03:37 web.1       |   created_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00,
13:03:37 web.1       |   updated_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00>,
13:03:37 web.1       |  #<Cover::Item:0x007fe1a6f4f418
13:03:37 web.1       |   id: 284,
13:03:37 web.1       |   cover_id: 64,
13:03:37 web.1       |   teaser_id: 214,
13:03:37 web.1       |   position: 3,
13:03:37 web.1       |   created_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 16:54:47 CEST +02:00,
13:03:37 web.1       |   updated_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00>,
13:03:37 web.1       |  #<Cover::Item:0x007fe1a6f4f080
13:03:37 web.1       |   id: 285,
13:03:37 web.1       |   cover_id: 64,
13:03:37 web.1       |   teaser_id: 210,
13:03:37 web.1       |   position: 4,
13:03:37 web.1       |   created_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 16:54:47 CEST +02:00,
13:03:37 web.1       |   updated_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00>,
13:03:37 web.1       |  #<Cover::Item:0x007fe1a6f4ebd0
13:03:37 web.1       |   id: 290,
13:03:37 web.1       |   cover_id: 64,
13:03:37 web.1       |   teaser_id: 54,
13:03:37 web.1       |   position: 5,
13:03:37 web.1       |   created_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 17:44:27 CEST +02:00,
13:03:37 web.1       |   updated_at: Wed, 08 Aug 2018 18:21:40 CEST +02:00>]
```

The cover model has act_as_list gem, but I don't understand what is changing the position of my items after saving. I don't have any position write query in my logs..

Comment: added... i push enter without finishing the message. As you can see the position of the item is changed but i cannot understand what is changing it...

Comment: I would `tail` your log files though the process. This will show you all the SQL queries that are executed and perhaps give you an idea of what's changing the position.

Comment: @jklina in development?

Comment: Whatever environment you happening to be testing in.

Comment: I try without success... i think is something related to the gem but I cannot understand why it has a gap between the position. In the log i cannot find any useful info